# Setting window styles with Tkinter/Tcl: no exit button

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter, tcl, window-style

I know that Tkinter is just a thin layer over Tcl/Tk. Tkinter you can do a few things to change the windows styling. One example would be `root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)`. This would change the window style, to that of a tool window. However, I'm looking to go a little bit lower level.

I suspect at some point Tcl/Tk refrences Windows [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czada357%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I'm pretty sure it would have to do this in order to set the window style and by extension the Tkinter window styling. I'm trying to give a Tkinter window what I'm pretty sure is the **WS_DLGFRAME** style. However, I'm unsure how to approach this.

I'm wondering where in the Tcl/Tk part of Tkinter does it assign windows styles, and what I'd have to add to get this style.

The end goal is to get a Tkinter window border style that looks like the one below (note how it lacks an exit button):

[image]

This is in Windows 7, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with C, download [Tk source code](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html).

I've looked quickly, and in this file:
`./win/tkWinWm.c` at line 3072 (`tk859-src.zip`), you have the function `static int WmAttributesCmd()`, dealing with `-toolwindow` as you've said, later updated by `UpdateWrapper()`.

So no easy way to change it, unless you change Tk source code.

Alternatively you might be able to use `FindWindow` and look for Tk's window class `TK_WIN_CHILD_CLASS_NAME` defined to be `TkChild`, and then use `SetWindowLongPtr( GWLP_STYLE, ...)` to change the style (but this requires some ffi call to C or other means).

I myself I'm not familiar with neither Tcl/Tk, so take it with a grain of salt. Why not try the Tcl/Tk community?

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite a bit more familiar with C than TCL. This seems to be on the right track.

Comment: Also, log a Feature Request for this against Tk itself: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=12997&atid=362997

Answer (score 5):

The following option instructs the window manager not to decorate the window (i.e no title bar and window buttons, plus no borders)

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

A false argument restores the decorations.

Comment: You might add that, with this technique you can draw whatever borders you want. Place a canvas so that it fills the frame then draw whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already aware of this method. It works, however I'm trying to go for a completely native look.