# How to get rounded edges in tkinter window in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Tkinter Window in windows 11 looks something like this :
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m1Dm.jpg)

Can anyone tell me how to do this is in windows 10

Comment: thats not a tkinter issue. thats windows 11 making all tabs appear rounded.

Comment: You do not get to control this properly from Tkinter, as it is implemented by the operating system. You have some limited options, e.g. as described in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973371/setting-window-styles-with-tkinter-tcl-no-exit-button, but I suspect this will not do what you want.

Comment: @KingTasaz I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: What I mean is that the fact that windows are rounded in the first place is because windows 11 has specific instructions to do so. Theres no extra code in tkinter that would allow for this. If I am wrong and there is away of doing this then sorry, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [customtkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) to get a modern UI. It is basically a modified version for tkinter.
For windows 10, I have created a window style using customtkinter which have round corners:

```py
# Only for windows 10/11 +

import customtkinter
from ctypes import windll
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

# Template Options
class CTkWindow(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self,
                app_title = "CTk", # Application name
                geometry = "500x300", # Enter window geometry 
                titlebar_color = "default", # Specify the color of top bar
                title_color = "default", # Title label color
                fg_color = "default", # fg_color of window
                resizable = True, # Resize window dynamically
                round_corner = 12, # corner_radius
                icon = None, # icon path
                justify = "left", # title justify
                style = "classic" # style
                ):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        transparent_color = self._apply_appearance_mode(['#f2f2f2','#000001'])
        self.config(background=transparent_color)
        self.attributes("-transparentcolor", transparent_color) # transparent_color will be the transparent color
        self.geometry(geometry)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.x = self.winfo_x()
        self.y = self.winfo_y()
        self.fullscreen = False
        self.GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
        self.WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000
        self.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080
        self.titlebar_color = ["white","black"] if titlebar_color=="default" else titlebar_color
        title_color = ["black","white"] if title_color=="default" else title_color
        self.header = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=round_corner, fg_color=self.titlebar_color,
                                           background_corner_colors=(transparent_color,transparent_color,None,None))
        self.header.grid(sticky="nwe", row=0)
        self.header.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.header.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.header.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.oldxyset)
        self.header.bind("<B1-Motion>",  self.move_window)
        self.header.bind("<Double-1>",  lambda e: self.max_window())
        
        fg_color = customtkinter.ThemeManager.theme["CTk"]["fg_color"] if fg_color=="default" else fg_color
            
        self.app = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=round_corner, bg_color=transparent_color, fg_color=fg_color,
                                     background_corner_colors=(fg_color,fg_color,None,None))
        self.app.grid(sticky="nsew", row=0,pady=(29,0))
        self.app.bind("<Map>", self.frame_mapped)
        
        if resizable==True:
            self.app.bind("<Motion>", self.change_cursor)
            self.app.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.resize)
            max_button_color = "yellow"
            hover_color = "#ffda71"
        else:
            max_button_color = "grey60"
            hover_color = "grey60"
            
        self.resizable = resizable
        self.ctkimage = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(customtkinter.__file__),"assets","icons","CustomTkinter_icon_Windows.ico")), size=(16,16))
        self.icon = self.ctkimage if icon is None else customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(icon), size=(16,16))
        self.title_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.header, width=10, image=self.icon, compound="left", text=f"  {app_title}", anchor="n", text_color=title_color)
        if justify=="center":
            self.title_label.grid(row=0, sticky="we", padx=(30,0), pady=7)
        else:
            self.title_label.grid(row=0, sticky="w", padx=8, pady=7)
         
        self.title_label.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.oldxyset)
        self.title_label._label.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.oldxyset)
        self.title_label.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_window)
        self.title_label.bind("<Double-1>",  lambda e: self.max_window())
        self.minmize = False
        self.style = style
        if style=="modern":
            self.button_close = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.header, corner_radius=10, width=10, height=10, text="",
                                                   hover_color="dark red", fg_color="red", command=self.close_window)
            self.button_close.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ne", padx=(0,15), pady=10)
            self.button_close.configure(cursor="arrow")

            self.button_max = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.header, corner_radius=10, width=10, height=10, text="",
                                                 hover_color=hover_color, fg_color=max_button_color, command=self.max_window)
            self.button_max.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ne", padx=10, pady=10)
            self.button_max.configure(cursor="arrow")

            self.button_min = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.header, corner_radius=10, width=10, height=10, text="",
                                                 hover_color="light green", fg_color="green", command=self.min_window)
            self.button_min.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ne", pady=10)
            self.button_min.configure(cursor="arrow")
        else:
            self.button_close = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.header, corner_radius=round_corner, width=40, height=30, text="✕",
                                                   hover_color="#c42b1c", fg_color="transparent", text_color=["black","white"],
                                                   background_corner_colors=(None,transparent_color,None,None), command=self.close_window)
            self.button_close.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ne", padx=0, pady=0)
            self.button_close.configure(cursor="arrow")
            self.button_close.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: self.change_bg(transparent_color, 1), add="+")
            self.button_close.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: self.change_bg(transparent_color, 0), add="+")
            
            self.button_max = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.header, corner_radius=0, width=40, height=30, text="□",text_color=["black","white"],
                                                 hover_color="#2d2d2d", fg_color="transparent", command=self.max_window)
            self.button_max.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ne", padx=0, pady=0)
            self.button_max.configure(cursor="arrow")

            self.button_min = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.header, corner_radius=0, width=40, height=30, text="—",text_color=["black","white"],
                                                 hover_color="#2d2d2d", fg_color="transparent", command=self.min_window)
            self.button_min.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ne", pady=0)
            self.button_min.configure(cursor="arrow")
        
    def change_bg(self, transparent_color, hover):
        if hover: 
            self.button_close.configure(background_corner_colors=("#c42b1c",transparent_color,"#c42b1c","#c42b1c"), fg_color="#c42b1c")
        else:
            self.button_close.configure(background_corner_colors=(self.titlebar_color,transparent_color,self.titlebar_color,self.titlebar_color),
                                        fg_color=self.titlebar_color)
            
    def geometry(self, geometry):
        super().geometry(geometry)
        
    def iconbitmap(self, icon):
        self.icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(icon), size=(16,16))
        self.title_label.configure(image=self.icon)
        
    def oldxyset(self, event):
        self.oldx = event.x
        self.oldy = event.y
        
    def move_window(self, event):
        if self.fullscreen==False:
            self.y = event.y_root - self.oldy
            self.x = event.x_root - self.oldx
            self.geometry(f'+{self.x}+{self.y}')
        
    def close_window(self):
        super().destroy()
        
    def frame_mapped(self, e):
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.state('normal')
        if self.minmize:
            self.fullscreen = False
            self.max_window()
        self.minmize = False
        
    def min_window(self):
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.overrideredirect(False)
        self.withdraw()
        self.state('iconic')
        if self.fullscreen:
            self.minmize = True
        
    def set_appwindow(self):
        hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.winfo_id())
        style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, self.GWL_EXSTYLE)
        style = style & ~self.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
        style = style | self.WS_EX_APPWINDOW
        res = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, self.GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
        self.wm_withdraw()
        self.after(10, lambda: self.wm_deiconify())
        
    def max_window(self):
        if self.resizable==True:
            if self.fullscreen==False:
                self.update_idletasks()
                self.overrideredirect(False)
                self.wm_state('zoomed')
                self.overrideredirect(True)
                self.after(10, lambda: self.set_appwindow())
                self.state('normal')
                self.fullscreen=True
                if self.style=="classic": self.button_max.configure(text="❒")
            else:
                self.geometry(f'+{self.x}+{self.y}')
                self.fullscreen=False
                if self.style=="classic": self.button_max.configure(text="□")
                
    def change_cursor(self, event):
        if (event.x in range(self.app.winfo_width()-10, self.app.winfo_width())
            and event.y in range(self.app.winfo_height()-10, self.app.winfo_height())):
            self.config(cursor="size_nw_se")
            return
        else:
            self.config(cursor="")
        
        if (event.x in range(self.app.winfo_width()-5, self.app.winfo_width())
            and event.y in range(0, self.app.winfo_height())):
            self.config(cursor="sb_h_double_arrow")
            return
        else:
            self.config(cursor="")

        if (event.x in range(0, self.app.winfo_width())
            and event.y in range(self.app.winfo_height()-5, self.app.winfo_height())):
            self.config(cursor="sb_v_double_arrow")
            return
        else:
            self.config(cursor="")
            
    def resize(self, event):
        if self.cget('cursor')=="size_nw_se":
            if event.x>100 and event.y>100:
                self.geometry(f"{event.x_root-self.x}x{event.y_root-self.y}")
        elif self.cget('cursor')=="sb_h_double_arrow":
            self.geometry(f"{event.x_root-self.x}x{self.winfo_height()}")
        elif self.cget('cursor')=="sb_v_double_arrow":
            self.geometry(f"{self.winfo_width()}x{event.y_root-self.y}")
            
    def configure(self, **kwargs):
        if "titlebar_color" in kwargs:
            self.titlebar_color = kwargs["titlebar_color"]
            self.header.configure(fg_color=self.titlebar_color)
        if "title" in kwargs:
            self.title_label.configure(text=f"  {kwargs['title']}")
        if "icon" in kwargs:
            self.icon = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(kwargs["icon"]), size=(16,16))
            self.title_label.configure(image=self.icon)
        if "fg_color" in kwargs:
            self.app.configure(fg_color=fg_color)
        if "title_color" in kwargs:
            self.title_label.configure(text_color=kwargs['title_color'])     

if __name__=="__main__":    
    window = CTkWindow()
    # put widget in window.app 
    window.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot windows 10]

More info here: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/discussions/736

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do rounded edges with the tkinter module. You might have to use something like PyQt5 (a GUI module with more features).